# Solution for ajax calls inside foreach

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, foreach

I have A json with widgets

> {"widgetname": "widget1", "widgetID": "FJRH585fKFJN234NC"}

I loop though the json and get html for each json object.

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "get_json.php",
    data: {action: "get_widgets", userID: user},
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        var r = 0;
        $.each(data, function() {
            var widgetID = this.widgetID;
            $.ajax({
                url: this.widgetname+".html",
                data: {},
                type: "GET",
                success: function(datas){
                    var parsed = $($.parseHTML(datas));
                    var parsed1 = parsed.filter("*").first().attr("data-item", data[r].widgetID);
                    $(".grid").append(parsed1);
                    r++;
                }
            });

        });
    }
});
```

For each json object I do an ajax call to get the html content of the widget.
This is not the right way.
My widgetID's are not set to the right widget because the ajax calls are not done before a new one starts.
How to do this in a proper way?

Comment: Wouldn't it perhaps be better to gather all ids first and then make a single call to the end point to get all records - depending on how many records you will have, calling endpoint with each iteration can be quite costly. Perhaps send the whole json that you have with your request and let server side code return what you're after?

Comment: In array foreach "this" should not use but try to use "$.each(data, unction(i, item) { alert(item.widgetname);});". "this" only use while DOM iteration.

Comment: Each widget has a html file where I get the widget content from, and the count of widgets is variable

Comment: Why min-vote? im here to learn how to do this in a proper way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one...
You put this code in success function.

```
success: function(datas){
        $.each(datas, function(i, item) {
          var parsed1 = parsed.filter("*").first().attr("data-item", item.widgetID);
          $(".grid").append(parsed1);
        });
}

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
   alert(item.widgetname);
});
```

Comment: Alright this solved my problem, but could someone explain me how to do this in a proper way? I heard from my collegue that this is not the proper way.

Comment: @JelleBotman $.each() use to access the data index oriented not object oriented, because collection itself an object.